# React Native: There is no route defined for key X Must be one of Y Z

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm working on an app with the following routing structure:

```
root // tab navigator
  A // stack navigator
    A1
    A2 -> B
  B // stack navigator
    B1
    B2
    B3 -> C
  C
```

The root navigation consists of a tab navigator. Two of the routes on that tab navigator (A and B) contain stack navigators.

I'm trying to make it so that whenever users click the B tab, the B stack resets, so the user is always served B1 when the B stack mounts.

I thought I could accomplish this by adding the following event to the icon that users click to navigate to B (my tab component is custom):

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'B' })],
}));
```

However, this throws:

```
Error: There is no route defined for key B.
Must be one of: 'A','A1','A2'
```

This bamboozles me. Does anyone know how I can force the B stack to reset to 0 programmatically? Any suggestions would be helpful!

```
// versions:
"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
"react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.4",
"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
```

Comment: related: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sketchy but I was able to get this running by saving the B router into a global namespace:

```
const BStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    B1: { screen: B1, },
    B2: { screen: B2, },
    B3: { screen: B3, },
  },
  { 
    initialRouteName: 'B1',
  }
)

BStack.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  global.B_NAVIGATOR = navigation; // could be stored in redux or elsewhere...
}
```

Then inside my root level tab navigator, I listened to hear if the user clicked the B tab. If so, I just reset the B stack navigator with `.popToTop()`:

```
class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (global.B_NAVIGATOR) global.B_NAVIGATOR.popToTop();
    this.props.navigation.navigate('B', {});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}>
        <Text>Link to B</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may have to do with build setup, I would get this in expo, even though I clearly had the route defined, and it "appeared" to reload the js. Stopping starting expo triggered a more complete build and the new routes would take effect.

Comment: Here, without expo, had to do the same, restart

Comment: Agreed, Even in Ejected projects, the "reload" doesn't seem to work. I had to rebuild the app to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I got this after I removed a StackNavigator and did not fully restart the app. My solution was to stop the app and run `expo start -c` which clears some cache on start.